# ADF Scan, Upload to Web application

Tags: windows, ocr, scanning

I search software to scan from ADF (Automatic Document Feeder) scanner and uploads to a web application.

Required features:

- Scans from ADF and flatbed
- Supports most ADF scanner hardware
- Runs on MS-Windows
- Creates PDF
- Uploads PDF to web form. Further editing via web form
- Optional: full text OCR, creating annotated PDFs
- Yearly licence should not cost more than 200$
- Daily usage should not need internet connection
- Free demo version should be available.

The web application which receives the PDFs can be adapted easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use of combination of ChronoScan + NemakiWare.

ChronoScan is compatible with TWAIN scanners, ADF or not. It can push scanned documents to any CMIS server.

NemakiWare is a CMIS server available for Windows/Mac/Linux.

[Here](http://www.chronoscan.org/doc/v1_0_0_40_now_add_alfresco_document_scanning_and_cmis_support.htm) is how to configure ChronoScan to upload PDFs to NemakiWare:

Just use the CMIS URL of NemakiWare as described at https://github.com/aegif/NemakiWare/wiki/Access-NemakiWare

You can then browse and download the PDFs from the NemakiWare webapp.

ChronoScan costs a 245 EUR one-time fee (no recurring cost unless you want to purchase maintenance).
NemakiWare is free (open source).
Disclaimer: I wrote part of NemakiWare.
You can also use Alfresco instead of NemakiWare, but it less easy to install.

Comment: The other answer (Drivve) looked good, too. But ChronoScan comes with a free version for home users. This way we can test the software first. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Drivve](https://www.drivve.com/us/products/image) suite for this, we have a network of A3 and A4 multi function device printers, all with ADFs and conventional flatbeds (in standard photocopier setup). Our system uses Drivve to email the user their scanned data directly, but this can be changed to web upload. I don't know your location so I can't quote a price, but there should be some local dealer near you that can arrange free demos, trials etc.